# rails - Searching across two combined fields with various matching

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

My user model has:

User (id, fname, lname)

I need a query to search for users by name. I had ben using:

```
@users = User.find( :all,
                      :select => 'users.*',
                      :conditions => ["fname || ' ' || lname LIKE ?", '%'+"James Bond"+'%']
                    )
```

If you search for James, the user (James Bond) is returned, but if you search for "Bond" nothing is returned. How can I update this query to return users by either fname,lname or fname and lname?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you specify it in RoR, but at the PostgreSQL level, it sounds like you might want to use trigram searches.  If you are using PostgreSQL version 9.1 or later you can combine that with "K Nearest Neighbor" (KNN) searches, to directly return the K best matches.  This is generally orders of magnitude faster than other "fuzzy" search techniques for names.

To install trigram support, if you have the contrib modules on your machine, type:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

Assuming that both name fields are `NOT NULL` (just to avoid cluttering the answer with `COALESCE` predicates), the index can be created with:

```
CREATE INDEX users_name ON users USING gist
  ((fname || ' ' || lname) gist_trgm_ops);
```

Here's the fun part, where you can find approximate matches from millions of records in a few milliseconds:

```
SELECT *
  FROM users
  ORDER BY (fname || ' ' || lname) <-> 'James Bond'
  LIMIT 10;
```

The `<->` operator is the "distance" operator.  When that is used for the `ORDER BY` clause against an index defined with `gist_trgm_ops` *and* you use a `LIMIT`, rows will be returned from the index in "best match" sequence.